# 403 from au.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt-mirror

does anyone know why the au.archive is broken?

I'm getting the below on multiple systems trying to update them and this has been the case for a couple of hours now. I've tried apt clean as well with no joy.

```
  Err:11 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic amd64 5.4.0-81.91
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Get:12 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 5.4.0.81.85 [1,900 B]
Get:13 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 5.4.0.81.85 [2,572 B]
Err:14 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-81 all 5.4.0-81.91
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Get:15 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-81-generic amd64 5.4.0-81.91 [1,410 kB]
Get:16 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 5.4.0.81.85 [2,440 B]
Fetched 28.4 MB in 48s (591 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic_5.4.0-81.91_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-5.4.0-81_5.4.0-81.91_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Have you tried switching to the main archive (provided by Canonical/Ubuntu) instead of using the *aarnet* provided mirror?   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors this report's it's fine btw.

Comment: Yep.. works on the main mirror.. but, don't really want to reconfigure all 30 vm's to use it..

Comment: One option is raising a ticket with *aarnet* about the issue and they'll fix it, I've done it many times with *iinet*, but tickets usually take time, and the issues usually resolve themselves before action for many packages anyway (ie. new update arrives & users don't want that package any more)...

Comment: FYI:  You may find it resolves itself next time the mirror sync's with the main archive (*which is many times per day for many mirrors*), but I've also not had it fixed this way thus resorting to *ticket* as per prior comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy fix**

Switch to the main archive or use a different mirror.  Mirrors can be found at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

**Slow fix**

One option is raising a ticket with *aarnet* about the issue and they'll fix it, I've done it many times with *iinet*, but tickets usually take time, and the issues usually resolve themselves before action for many packages anyway (ie. *new update arrives & users don't want that package any more*)..

**Tickets have been raised**

I've spoken (*typed?*) with users experiencing the same issue on IRC (#ubuntu), and one has reported they'll file a ticket (bug reports) with *aarnet*.

I've since switched to another *focal* box myself that was using mirror.aarnet.edu.au & experienced the same error; thus I've emailed the "*AARNET Mirror Team*" about the issue, so it's been ticketed, so the fix should occur in due course.

Comment: I ended up switching the archive on all of them because the security fix was ssh so couldn't really wait.. all good. I guess I stick with the main mirror.

Comment: SD-29905 is the AARNET ticket i was given.

Comment: Steele Cooke of *Aarnet* has responded that the issues they now believe are resolved.

Comment: Thank you. I'll turn one back and see what happens.

Peter.